# How can I print a highlighted pdf document on Document Viewer?

Tags: 20.04, pdf

I've been using Document Viewer to highlight some important parts of my pdf documents, and I want it to stay highlighted. How can I keep my highlights visible on the documents when I go and print them? Also will the document be effected if it's opened and printed using other pdf editors and viewers?

Answer (score 1):

Your highlights will be preserved in the PDF provided you save the document. You can just save it with the same name, or save it under another name.

Evince will faithfully continue to show the highlights if you reopen the file. How it works in other viewers will depend. At least also in Google Chrome, highights and notes are well preserved.

Comment: This is not true. I try to print a PDF with highlights and the printer prints them too.

Comment: @VarunAgrawal Sure? I have to admit that I print rarely so I did not explicitly test. Anyway, I could remove these statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been having the same issue as the OP using Document Viewer.

Highlighting added while in Document Viewer will not carry over to "Print Preview" or to the printed result when opened from within Document Viewer. The printed page lacks any highlighting, even though it shows on-screen.

Somebody suggested trying Okular, which I did. Same problem until I rehighlighted while in Okular. Then the highlighting finally stuck and now shows in "Print Preview" and in the printed result.

After saving while in Okular, the rehighlighted PDF will also appear correctly in "Print Preview" when opened in Document Viewer.